# Spring-boot: Why custom ssh (CRaSH) commands not working inside IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created some custom ssh commands (CRaSH).
If they are in my current project as a source and I run my code inside my ide (IntelliJ), it is working fine.
But if my commands are in a dependent library (yes the .java files are in the jar in the commands/crash directory), they are not working. They are not even listed when I use the "help" command. And there is not error log at all.
But if I create my package (using maven) and running it outside my ide, it is working fine!

Is it because Intellij is using it's own class loader?
Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Without some code it's hard to find that out. It could be anything.

Comment: I can't see what the code itself had to do with that. It seems to me more a question of configuration or something like that. My commands classes are working fine. They are just not loaded when running from inside IntelliJ if they are in a jar.